# rank with the sum

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is the table:

```
category         weightage      As_of_date      
123abc           50             1/1/2020
456abc           100            1/2/2020
456abc           100            1/3/2020
678def           200            1/4/2020
678def           200            1/4/2020
123def           50             2/1/2020
123def           50             2/1/2020
123def           50             2/3/2020
123def           50             2/1/2020
123def           50             6/7/2020
```

where I want to rank the category based on weightage desc, expected results:

```
category         weightage      As_of_date     dense_rank     
123abc           50             1/1/2020       4
456abc           100            1/2/2020       3
456abc           100            1/3/2020       3
678def           200            1/4/2020       1
678def           200            1/4/2020       1
123def           50             2/1/2020       2
123def           50             2/1/2020       2
123def           50             2/3/2020       2 
123def           50             2/1/2020       2
123def           50             6/7/2020       2
```

what was already tried: `select desnse_rank() over (partition by category order by weightage desc)`, but I need to rank it based on sum(weightage) per category.

Comment: sum(weightage) per category you mean ?

Comment: yeah, based on category @trillion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a CTE you can do the calculations one by one. First calculate the dense rank for sum per category (ranked_by_sum), then join back to the original table to get the dense rank value for the individual rows:

```
WITH test_data (category, weightage, as_of_date) AS
(
SELECT '123abc',50, TO_DATE('1/1/2020','DD/MM/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '456abc',100,TO_DATE('1/2/2020','DD/MM/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '456abc',100,TO_DATE('1/3/2020','DD/MM/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '678def',200,TO_DATE('1/4/2020','DD/MM/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '678def',200,TO_DATE('1/4/2020','DD/MM/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '123def',50, TO_DATE('2/1/2020','DD/MM/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '123def',50, TO_DATE('2/1/2020','DD/MM/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '123def',50, TO_DATE('2/3/2020','DD/MM/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '123def',50, TO_DATE('2/1/2020','DD/MM/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '123def',50, TO_DATE('6/7/2020','DD/MM/YYYY') FROM DUAL
), ranked_by_sum (category,sum_weightage, drnk)
AS
(
SELECT category, SUM(weightage),DENSE_RANK () OVER ( 
        ORDER BY SUM(weightage) DESC )
  FROM test_data 
  GROUP BY category
)
SELECT t.category, t.weightage, t.as_of_date, r.drnk
  FROM test_data t 
       JOIN ranked_by_sum r ON t.category = r.category
  ORDER BY r.drnk DESC

CATEGO  WEIGHTAGE AS_OF_DATE        DRNK
------ ---------- ----------- ----------
123abc         50 01-JAN-2020          4
456abc        100 01-FEB-2020          3
456abc        100 01-MAR-2020          3
123def         50 02-JAN-2020          2
123def         50 06-JUL-2020          2
123def         50 02-JAN-2020          2
123def         50 02-JAN-2020          2
123def         50 02-MAR-2020          2
678def        200 01-APR-2020          1
678def        200 01-APR-2020          1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without a self-join using `SUM` as an analytic function in a nested sub-query:

```sql
SELECT category,
       weightage,
       as_of_date,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY total_weightage DESC) AS dense_rank
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         SUM(weightage) OVER (PARTITION BY category) AS total_weightage
  FROM   table_name t
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (category, weightage, as_of_date) AS
SELECT '123abc',50, DATE'2020-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '456abc',100,DATE'2020-02-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '456abc',100,DATE'2020-03-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '678def',200,DATE'2020-04-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '678def',200,DATE'2020-04-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '123def',50, DATE'2020-01-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '123def',50, DATE'2020-01-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '123def',50, DATE'2020-03-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '123def',50, DATE'2020-01-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '123def',50, DATE'2020-07-06' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | CATEGORY | WEIGHTAGE | AS_OF_DATE | DENSE_RANK |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 678def | 200 | 01-APR-20 | 1 |
> | 678def | 200 | 01-APR-20 | 1 |
> | 123def | 50 | 02-JAN-20 | 2 |
> | 123def | 50 | 02-MAR-20 | 2 |
> | 123def | 50 | 06-JUL-20 | 2 |
> | 123def | 50 | 02-JAN-20 | 2 |
> | 123def | 50 | 02-JAN-20 | 2 |
> | 456abc | 100 | 01-MAR-20 | 3 |
> | 456abc | 100 | 01-FEB-20 | 3 |
> | 123abc | 50 | 01-JAN-20 | 4 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5987d1074b9099e99a11505c477826e5)*

Comment: @Eric . . . I think this is the better solution because it avoids an unnecessary `JOIN`.